# Type of A field is its Class Name. What is this called in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

I new to C#, Sometime I see C# code like this

```
public class ClassName
{    
     ClassName field;
}
```

It mean the field type the same as Class name. WHat this mean and called in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reference to an instance of the type itself. E.g. An element in a linked list could reference the next element or if the type was a WebPage, it could have a reference to another WebPage.